# Do we need separate Unattended service account for each SharePoint Server 2013 BI service applications?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, configuration, best-practices, business-intelligence, secure-store

SharePoint 2013 - I'm planning to use 'unattended service account' method of Secure Store Service - for Excel, Performance Point and Visio services. I'm about to create Active directory accounts for them.

Question: Do we need separate Active directory accounts for each service
DomainName\ExcelUnattendedAccount
DomainName\PPSUnattendedAccount
DomainName\VisioUnattendedAccount

(or)

Can I have just one Active Directory account DomainName\SharePointUnattendedAccount ?

Are there any drawbacks having a single account? Any best practice around this? For all the three services the data sources are going to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unattended service account is a universal account that provides equal data access to all authorized users. You can use one account for all services or one account for each services application.

Its depend upon your secuirty, if you want restrict it to specific datasource of the Service App then you need dedicated account otherwise you can use one for all.

Answer (score 0):

The unattended service account is a universal account that provides equal data access to all authorized users. You can use one account for all services or one
for each